# Can WP7 Silver Light Gesture Listener be added to a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on a small Windows Phone 7 Silver Light app. I simply want a context menu to pop up over an item in a Listbox when the user taps and holds on the respective entry. I've read through several posts and the most common answer given is to use the Silverlight toolkit. I was excited since I already have it set up and use it for a few other things in the app. So I found a tutorial that explains how to set it up on a button. It failed when I tried because I was setting the content for the button twice:

```
    <Button Width="Auto" MinWidth="460" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button.Content>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="GestureListener_Hold" />
            <StackPanel ..... >
                .......
            </<StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Which tells me "The property 'Content' is et more than once.
So after searching again I found a nice article, http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/85263.aspx, which shows that I can move the statement to look more like:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation.....>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="GestureListener_Hold" />  
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Which tells me "A value of type 'GestureListener' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

I'd appreciate any help on either method or a brand new one. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the GestureListener as the value of the GestureService.GestureListener attached property:

```
<Button Width="Auto" MinWidth="460" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"> 
    <Button.Content> 
        <StackPanel ..... > 
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="GestureListener_Hold" />
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            ....... 
        </<StackPanel> 
    </Button.Content> 
</Button>
```

For what it's worth, the toolkit already includes a ContextMenu helper. See [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API)

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the quick response! I knew it had to be something simple I overlooked.

Comment: No problem...don't forget to tip your waiter (i.e. accept the answer). Baby needs a new pair of badges... ;)

Comment: I went with the ContextMenu helper you posted, makes it much easier :)